# Need help installing openvpn-2.3.7.zip from source

Tags: software-installation, permissions, openvpn

I downloaded openvpn-2.3.7.zip and unzipped it to my /home directory.

Next I did the following:

```
username@hostname:~$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for username:~$
```

(After keying in the password I am in the root directory, right? That means I have root permissions to perform whatever I wish??)

```
root@hostname:~# apt-get install libssl-dev liblzo2-dev libpam0g-dev checkinstall build-essential -y

root@hostname:~# cd /home/username/openvpn-2.3.7
root@hostname:/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7# ./configure
```

(a list of messages follows)

```
root@hostname:/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7# make
```

(a list of messages follows)

```
root@hostname:/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7# checkinstall
```

I encountered some errors and do not know how to resolve them and would appreciate your help.

Below is the log:

```
Installing with make install...

========================= Installation results ===========================
make install-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7'
Making install in build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/build'
Making install in msvc
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/build/msvc'
Making install in msvc-generate
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/build/msvc/msvc-generate'
make[5]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/build/msvc/msvc-generate'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/build/msvc/msvc-generate'
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/build/msvc/msvc-generate'
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/build/msvc'
make[5]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/build/msvc'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/build/msvc'
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/build/msvc'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/build/msvc'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/build'
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/build'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/build'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/build'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/build'
Making install in distro
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/distro'
Making install in rpm
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/distro/rpm'
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/distro/rpm'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/distro/rpm'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/distro/rpm'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/distro'
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/distro'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/distro'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/distro'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/distro'
Making install in include
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/include'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/include'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 openvpn-plugin.h '/usr/local/include'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/include'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/include'
Making install in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/src'
Making install in compat
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/src/compat'
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/src/compat'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/src/compat'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/src/compat'
Making install in openvpn
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/src/openvpn'
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/src/openvpn'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/sbin'
/bin/bash ../../libtool --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c openvpn '/usr/local/sbin'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c openvpn /usr/local/sbin/openvpn
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/src/openvpn'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/src/openvpn'
Making install in openvpnserv
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/src/openvpnserv'
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/src/openvpnserv'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/src/openvpnserv'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/src/openvpnserv'
Making install in plugins
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/src/plugins'
Making install in auth-pam
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/src/plugins/auth-pam'
make[5]: Entering directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/src/plugins/auth-pam'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/doc/openvpn'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 README.auth-pam '/usr/local/share/doc/openvpn'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib/openvpn/plugins'
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/lib/openvpn': No such file or directory
make[5]: *** [install-pluginLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/src/plugins/auth-pam'
make[4]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/src/plugins/auth-pam'
make[3]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/src/plugins'
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7/src'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/username/openvpn-2.3.7'
make: *** [install] Error 2

**** Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

Cleaning up...OK

Bye.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This prosses cannot create the file /usr/local/lib/openvpn/plugins

```
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib/openvpn/plugins'
```

Because the file /usr/local/lib/openvpn does not exist

```
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/lib/openvpn': No such file or directory
```

Make it like this

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/lib/openvpn
```

Try again

Comment: Are you telling me that whoever wrote the programming code for openvpn-2.3.7.zip had omitted this step and left it to the user to manually create `/usr/local/lib/openvpn` ? If yes, that is bad programming code, yes? I will now try out your recommendation and feedback here.

Comment: I'm not say that per say, but that is the first error and all following errors mention plug ins,  so if that folder is not present maybe other mentioned plug ins could not be installed

Comment: Good news. Your suggestion worked. Still I don't understand why the people who wrote the code did not wish `/usr/local/lib/openvpn` to be created automatically.

Comment: I'm almost sure that is not "bad programming code" because i didn't had this problem when compiling OpenVPN 2.3.7 in Ubuntu 15.04